# Read String Values in an IList or Array Sequencially C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, ilist

I want to be able to read a text file and put the string values in either an IList<> or an Array[].

I want to be able to read the values in the IList<> or array[] sequentially.

I want to be able to read the first value in the IList<> or array[] keep the pointer 
or position, process the read value, then come back for the next value in sequence,
read the value keep the pointer, process  the value and come back for the next in
sequence till the end of the list or array is reached.

I don't know if that is the most efficient algo, but how do I do that in C#?

If its possible to do that with a class, that will be great!

Comment: You might want to do some research on `StreamReader` for reading files and putting their content into strings

Comment: Hi James, What have your tried yourself? Its not the idea that we make your homework. Try it yourself then come with some exmaples what you tried and we can help you with that.

Comment: how is the input file formatted? Is it possible to read line by line and save it?

Comment: An Array ***is*** an IList

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function Process to process a line, you can do this:

```
foreach( var line in File.ReadLines("file.txt"))
{
  Process(line);
}
```

Comment: I already did the reading of the file. the rest of the alogrithm is what will be helpful

Comment: You don't give any information about it. Only "processing". If you have a question about this processing, put in more details.